# How can I link User credentials in Realm Mobile Platform?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

For example (taken in Realm's docs):

```
let usernameCredential = Credential.usernamePassword(username: "username", password: "password", actions: [.createAccount])
let googleCredential   = Credential.google(token: "Google token")
let facebookCredential = Credential.facebook(token: "Facebook token")
let iCloudCredential   = Credential.iCloud(token: "iCloud token")
```

How can I link together these accounts so that any of these accounts connects to the same Realm?

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately no way yet to cross-link accounts in the Developer Edition. There is so far a technical limitation in the Realm Sync Engine, which prevented us from supporting that right from the start.

While linking accounts in the Realm Authentication System is relatively easy to achieve, to allow that generically, you would also need to take  all Realms into account which may exist already for the both linked identities and would need to merge those. We're still working on the feature of merging Realms, which were independently created.